# How to use regexmapper based routing in Zuul? PatternServiceRouteMapper not working?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

What I try to achieve is a routing for example:
`http://zuul-host:8080/v1/foo/hello` to my service `foo-v1`, resource `hello`

I'm trying out the **regexmapper** example described at http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html

My problem is that I see that a service called `foo-v1` gets mapped to `/v1/foo` in the `PatternServiceRouteMapper` but then I'm not able to call that route. It's also no visible at `/mappings`. Do I have to activate that route somewhere?

### Setup

#### Foo Service

`application.properties`

```
server.port=9092
spring.application.name=foo-v1
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.healthcheck.enable=true
```

#### Zuul

My configuration class `Routings.java`. I added some sysout log output for the service mapping and I get `foo-v1 -> v1/foo` in the log. Therefore this mapping should be active.

```
@Configuration
public class Routings {

    @Bean
    public PatternServiceRouteMapper serviceRouteMapper() {
        return new PatternServiceRouteMapper(
            "(?<name>^.+)-(?<version>v.+$)",
            "${version}/${name}") {
            @Override
            public String apply(final String serviceId) {                
                String route =  super.apply(serviceId);
                System.out.println(serviceId + " -> " +route);
                return route;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My `ZuulApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@ComponentScan
public class ZuulApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RefreshScope
    @ConfigurationProperties("zuul")
    public ZuulProperties zuulProperties() {
        return new ZuulProperties();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the solution.

Remove `ignoredServices: '*'` from the zuul config.

This happens if you work through the examples. They start with explicitly configured routes and ignore dynamic routings. It's in the documentation but made no sense to me at that point :-)

> To skip having a service automatically added, set zuul.ignored-services to a list of service id patterns.

When using the regexmapper we start using services that get added automatically and that's the feature we disabled with `ignoredServices: '*'`

Comment: Can you please provider your application.properties from the zuul server?